# New to Java - What's a great resource for a beginner programmer

Tags: java

I am a student going to university to learn computer science this Fall, and I want to get ahead on Java programming.  What are the most helpful and easy to understand programming tutorials on the web?  I've been to a few sites, but they all skip the explanation on certain key concepts (like what a package or imports are!)

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: I think books are better source to learn. You need a strong foundation because it is gonna be your profession. Sometimes tutorial focus you in how to do things but not why. I can suggest you Ivor Horton's Beginning Java 2 and Bruce Eckel's Thinking in Java (Not sure if it has an updated version). They have more extensive explanations about topics. The important thing is to learn programming and its theory, not particularly a language. Good luck.

Comment: I'll look these up on Amazon, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend my blog:

http://howtoprogramwithjava.com

It's a new site I just put up to help teach the fundamental concepts of Java, and I feel like it's fairly simple to use.  I've had great feedback so far and was featured on lifehacker:

http://lifehacker.com/5933073/learn-to-code

Hope that helps and best of luck at school! :)

Comment: Hey thanks, your site seems pretty great!  Thanks Trevor

Comment: Your first post (http://howtoprogramwithjava.com/programming-101-the-5-basic-concepts-of-any-programming-language/) was very helpful to me very good writing style

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend the oracle tutorials found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).
They pretty much walk you through from the very basics.
They don't really teach you how to program, but do teach you what the language can do.

On there the "[Learning the Java Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)" is a good place to start. It gives more of an overview of programming in general and covers most of the basics, before getting into java.

Personally I find you generally get what you pay for, and the free online tutorials (with the exception of the oracle tutorials) are generally not terribly good. I would invest in a good book (or a few) as they tend to be better organized.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I've seen these tutorials, but they're not really well organized and only mildly helpful.  Are there any easier to follow sites?

Comment: Yeah that site has a ton of content. Updated answer with a second link to the more beginner section.